# Display Featured Article of Specific Category Using a Module in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am working with different modules in Joomla (2.5) in order to display a variety of things. Right now I am trying to show the featured article of a specific category.

For example: I have three different pages, all showing articles specified by its own category.

`Bikes`
`Gears`
`Media`

Each of these pages has a range of article (lets says 20 each). Each of these sets of articles has a featured article. So there is a featured article for Bikes, Gears and Media.

My problem is trying to get this featured article to display at the top of each main page. I've tried using the `Articles by Category` module and I've looked into the `Article - Newsflash` module as well as looking at the code of the front page where a "featured article" typically appears.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a module I may be able to use?

Answer (score 2):

No module needed. Here are two ways you can accomplish this:

In the Blog Layout Options for your Category Blog menu item, set Article Order to Featured Articles Order.

Alternatively, make a new parent category for each existing category and put the featured article in the parent. Set your blog page to show the parent category and the subcategories. Hide the subcategory headings on the page with menu item settings and/or CSS.